# Printing a number in binary in C

Tags: c, number-systems

I wrote a short function whose purpose is simple: Print the binary representation of number to the console. I also aim to be as portable as possible, hence my use of `CHAR_BIT` and `+` instead of `|` in case the character encoding for `'0'` happens to be odd. Is my code as good and portable as I intended?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define SIZE (sizeof(unsigned long long)*CHAR_BIT)
int putb(const unsigned long long n) {
    char b[SIZE+1];
    for (unsigned i = SIZE; i--; b[i^SIZE-1] = ((char)(n>>i)&1)+'0');
    b[SIZE] = 0;
    return puts(b);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious portability problem is that we have `b[i^SIZE-1]` where I'd expect `b[SIZE-1-i]`.  That looks like an error of judgement: it produces the same results when `SIZE` is an exact power of 2, but not otherwise.

Instead of the `SIZE` preprocessor macro, I'd probably use a constant within the function:

```
    static const size_t length = sizeof n * CHAR_BIT;
```

If you do stick with the macro, consider `#undef SIZE` afterwards so it's available to other code.

As a style issue, I don't like the `for` loop with empty body on the same line.  That looks more like code-golf than something that's intended to be readable - especially with the "work" of the loop stuffed into the control expression.

We really want the cast to `char` to happen to the sum, since `char`+`char` yields `int`.  That said, `gcc -pedantic -Wconversion` doesn't complain without it.

I would write the character constant `0` as `'\0'` to better convey the intent.  That's especially important as we have `'0'` close by.

You might find it easier, clearer and more efficient to work backwards from the least-significant bit:

```
int putb(unsigned long long n)
{
    char b[(sizeof n * CHAR_BIT) + 1];
    char *p = b + sizeof b;
    *--p = '\0';
    for (; p-- > b;  n >>= 1) {
        *p = '0' + (char)(n & 1);
    }
    return puts(b);
}
```

This gives the option of a version that doesn't print leading zeros (and therefore modified to accept any size integer):

```
#include <stdint.h>

int putb(uintmax_t n)
{
    char b[(sizeof n * CHAR_BIT) + 1];
    char *p = b + sizeof b;
    *--p = '\0';
    do {
        *--p = '0' + (n & 1);
    } while (n >>= 1);
    return puts(p);
}
```

This one is trivially modified to add a `0b` prefix, should that be desired.

Comment: I like this new approach.

Comment: *it happens to produce the same results when SIZE is an exact power of 2, but not otherwise* - It's not just a coincidence; it's a known bithack which is mostly useful in assembly language, where `31 - reg` can't be done in a single instruction on most ISAs (ARM has an `rsb` reverse-subtract instruction) but `reg ^= 31` can.  I've maybe only seen it in the context of how GCC implements `__builtin_clz()` in terms of x86's `bsr` instruction, which produces a bit-index instead of leading-zero count.  The builtin (like the instruction) doesn't define the result for input=0, so GCC can use ^=31.

Comment: 100% agreed the XOR bithack is not a good idea in this code, though!  If you want to write something easily readable that's more likely to compile to efficient asm given C's lack of a rotate builtin or capturing carry-out from a left shift, looping backwards like you're doing and taking the low bit is good.  (@user16217248).  (In x86 asm you'd want something like `shl rcx, 1` / `mov rax, '0'` / `adc rax, 0` to turn each bit into an ASCII digit via the carry flag, starting from the top bit.  Or various other options like `shl` / `setc al` / `add al, '0'`. Or use SSE2 to do 16 bits in parallel.)

Comment: `char b[length+1];` Is this considered a variable-length array, even though in practice it's not?

Comment: Yes, it's a VLA (which is standard since C11, and widely available before), because the value of a `static const` variable is not an _integer constant expression_ in C, even when initialised from one.  If you want extreme (i.e. pre-C11) portability, declare `char b[sizeof n * CHAR_BIT + 1]` and `char *p = b + sizeof b - 1`.

Comment: Yes @Peter, it's not coincidence and I didn't mean to imply it was.  Just that we should be leaving our compiler to make such micro-optimisations where appropriate (and to know when not to, according to the actual values involved).  I'll re-word that bit.

Comment: @user16217248: Yes in C it's a VLA, but compilers will in practice see the compile-time constant and not waste instructions, as long as you enable optimization.  With `-O0` (https://godbolt.org/z/jenhMx7W3), clang stores a pointer to the array into a local var, like it would do with an actual VLA.  Fun fact: in C++ it's not a VLA.  In C++, a `const int` initialized with a constant expression becomes `constexpr`.

Comment: (Unfortunately with `-O3`, both GCC and clang compile this to amazingly bad code, especially clang which does 45 `vpinsrb` instructions + 3x `vmovd` to shuffle 1 byte at a time into SIMD vectors.  As in [How to perform the inverse of \_mm256\_movemask\_epi8 (VPMOVMSKB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21622212) / [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675) .  And [Convert 16 bits mask to 16 bytes mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67201469) has a version that does printing order, since that's what the question secretly wanted)

Comment: @PeterCordes The problem with the VLA is that is no longer standard C in C11 and newer.

Comment: @TobySpeight Last version with `putb(0)` does not print any digits.  Better to print `"0\n"`.  Consider a `do { ... } while (n)` loop.

Comment: @TobySpeight  VLA `char b[length+1];` defeats "aim to be as portable as possible" as "VLA (which is standard since C11" overstates.  In C99, VLAs are standard, yet in C11, C17, C23, such arrays are _optionally_ supported.  There is no need for a VLA solution as the buffer width is small and constant.

Comment: Thanks @chux - code modified accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my code as good and portable as I intended?

Not quite.

---

**C23**

Use specifier `"%b"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
printf("%0*llb\n", ULLONG_WIDTH, n);  // Print all bits
printf("%llb\n", n);  // Print significant bits
```

---

**For highly portability C99 onward**

- OP used a constant sized buffer - good.  Variable length arrays since C11 are optionally supported.
- Do not assume no padding bits as with `sizeof(unsigned long long)*CHAR_BIT`.  The number of *value* bits in an `unsigned long long` depends on `ULLONG_MAX`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359
/* Number of bits in inttype_MAX, or in any (1<<k)-1 where 0 <= k < 2040 */
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))
#define SIZE (IMAX_BITS(ULLONG_MAX))
...
```

Consider simply code such as below which looks at the least significant bit per iteration.

```
int putb(unsigned long long n) {
    char b[SIZE+1];
    b[SIZE] = '\0';
    for (unsigned i = SIZE; i-- > 0; ) {
      b[i] = (char) ((n&1) + '0');
      n >>= 1;
    }
    return puts(b);
}
```

---

**Pre-C99**

There is no `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Presence of padding bits may cause the buffer to be slightly oversized, but is that particularly harmful?  Compared to the readability of the alternative, and the fact we're doing I/O, it seems irrelevant.

Comment: @TobySpeight "Presence of padding bits may cause the buffer to be slightly oversized, but is that particularly harmful?" --> No - an extra `char` or so in a small local buffer is insignificant.  Yet code miscalculates with [`for (; p-- > b;  n >>= 1) {`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/285446/29485) the number of bits to print.  It prints extra leading "0" characters when the type is padded.

Comment: Ah yes, of course.  An alternative is to use an all-ones constant of same type (i.e. `~0ULL`) and shift that along with `n` as the count (`for unsigned long long i = ~0ULL;  i;  i >>= 1)`).

Comment: @TobySpeight true, yet I find `for (unsigned i = SIZE; i-- > 0; ) {` more direct.